# What all can I learn while using Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I have been using Ubuntu for 3 months now. I was using Windows 7 before that. My experience with Ubuntu makes me to forget about Windows. I am learning commands and the ways to do each and every thing from terminal. Although, I don't have much knowledge about Ubuntu right now but I want to learn more and more about Ubuntu. What else can I learn about Ubuntu? Apart from learning commands, what else can I learn?

Comment: Not a lot if you ask something like that here... we need problems we can answer not something to guess ;) http://discourse.ubuntu.com/ is more suited for this kind of questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you learn commands you learn how the system works. If you would use the GUI interface be it in Ubuntu or Windows, in the back they all use the same commands.

There are many new things you can learn in Ubuntu, or any other Linux distro for that matter.

As a suggestion, perhaps you could learn how to automate some stuff like making a script for a command that you normally use.
Here is a very small tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting

Anyhow this is just a sugestion but there are other things you could do, and you will learn them sooner or later. Just keep using Ubuntu :)